# How do you proceed to demonstrate that c = t (1 + r)?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

Let *c* be an approximation of the true value, *t*. Assuming that the relative error of *c* is *r*.
Show that *c* = *t*(1 + *r*)

Comment: The relative error, $r$, will be given by $\left|\frac{c-t}{t}\right|$. Can you pick it up from there?

Comment: Would the next step be r = (c-t)/t followed by rt = c - t ?

Comment: Assuming $c - t$ is nonnegative and $t \neq 0$, then yes. Otherwise you will have to work with the absolute value of these numbers.